# How can i change the arrows of vue-carousel to a base64 image

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is a way to change the arrow of

https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel

to a base64 image?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no built-in way provided by the library, but I would suggest you to simply add it as a `background-image` to the arrow element.

Like this:

```
.VueCarousel-navigation-prev {
    background-image: 'data:image/png; base64, ...'; // add your image as base64
    font-size: 0; // to hide the unicode arrow provided by the library

    // ... your custom styles (height, width...)
}
```

And then the same for the next button:

```
.VueCarousel-navigation-prev{ /* same here */ }
```